# How do I update an application that's installed using Ubuntu Make?

Tags: 14.04

I'm installing Android Studio using Ubuntu Make. How can I upgrade the Android Studio version using Ubuntu Make? I didn't see any options to update, only `--verbose` and `--remove`.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not update via make .

If you are already using Android Studio, you can update via the built in Update mechanism (Check For Updates); make sure you switch to the canary or beta channels if you're not being offered an update.

To configure automatic update settings, see the Updates dialog of your IDE Preferences or settings. You can then switch to either the canary or beta channels. (The default is "stable" but probably that one fails to automatically inform of updates).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu make can't update your Android Studio installation. To update use the built-in updater of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I just rerun the installation command on my IDE's. For example: `sudo umake ide webstorm` to updated webstorm. This is assuming a major version update that cannot be handled through the IDE itself.